# Handling errors with Braintree in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, braintree

I am using Braintree to process payments via my web application, no problems so far, plenty of documentation but just a little unsure of how to handle errors in my controller. I don't think I should be looking to display all the error messages back to the user as that could pose a security risk but I would like to handle my errors better than I do now, perhaps capturing a selection of generic errors?

The point of the question here is how would I go about capturing these, within a `rescue` or create a method that errors would go through and then display some custom messages for certain errors?

At the moment I have a very simple controller action

```
@result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
            amount: @amount,
            payment_method_nonce: params[:payment_method_nonce],
            options: {
              submit_for_settlement: true
            }
          )
if @result.success?
  redirect_to thank_you_path
else
  flash[:alert] = 'Something went wrong while processing your transaction. Please try again!'
  gon.client_token = generate_client_token
  render :new
end
```

I just display a generic "Something went wrong" message when @result is not successful.

Are there better ways to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

The result is an instance of an object, [having the whole information about transaction status](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/ruby#unsuccessful-result).

You might extract whatever information you want and print it out to the client.

E.g. to group the messages by the error code, one might use smth like this:

```
unless @result.success?
  flash[:alert] = case @result.transaction.processor_response_code.to_s
                  when /^2/ then "Contact bank"
                  else "Something went wrong"
                  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I notice that there a lot of status codes that can be returned https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/processor-responses/authorization-responses, I don't want to print each message as returned, more like if codes `2002, 2003, 2004` print `Contact bank`. How would i group these together and present in my controller

Comment: By writing a code, that groups the desired messages together, and presents them in the controller. This site is not “please write a code for me for free” site.

Comment: I'm not asking for a handout, just a pointer in the right direction, a resource to look at please. Im looking for a best practice on how to do this in Rails. Im thinking a method that takes the result object and finds the status code, but is one big case statement an efficient way to handle this ?

Comment: Thank you, so there is nothing wrong in using a case statement then ?

Comment: `case` is just fine everywhere, why?